# Python lmfit gives very small chi square; how to scale residuals

Tags: python, python-3.x, chi-squared, lmfit

My files with NIR spectra (x,y)  do not provide error information. I am doing a blackbody plus power law fit, code below; according to the resulting parameter values and the respective plots it seems to work correctly. However the chi square values are very small as the sample below shows. The documentation says ***the residuals should be scaled correctly***. What are the **exact** steps to do this? Thanks for any help.

```
def bb(x, T, const):
    from scipy.constants import h,k,c
    x = 1e-6 * x 
    return const*2*h*c**2 / (x**5 * (np.exp(h*c / (x*k*T)) - 1)) 

def powerlaw(x,A,p):
    return A*x**p


mod= Model(bb) + Model(powerlaw)
pars  = mod.make_params(T=2000,const=2*1e-21,A=2*np.average(y),p=-1.0)                          
result = mod.fit(y,pars,x=x)
print((result.fit_report()))
```

```
#Parameters
T=    (result.params['T'].value)
const=(result.params['const'].value)
A=    (result.params['A'].value)
p=    (result.params['p'].value)
---------------------------------
 T:      1403.30461 +/- 4.19860373 (0.30%) 
line 67  [[Model]]
    (Model(bb) + Model(powerlaw))
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 69
    # data points      = 5362
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 5.6981e-29
    reduced chi-square = 1.0635e-32
    Akaike info crit   = -394752.758
    Bayesian info crit = -394726.409
[[Variables]]
    T:      1403.30461 +/- 4.19860373 (0.30%) (init = 2000)
    const:  6.9272e-26 +/- 8.9056e-28 (1.29%) (init = 2e-21)
    A:      2.1975e-15 +/- 7.9268e-18 (0.36%) (init = 4.309166e-15)
    p:     -2.57314708 +/- 0.01807976 (0.70%) (init = -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, the only place where the `lmfit` documentation says anything about the scale of the uncertainties it does say exactly how this is done.

See:  https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html#uncertainties-in-variable-parameters-and-their-correlations

Quoting that:

```
In principle, the scale of the uncertainties in the Parameters is closely
tied to the goodness-of-fit statistics chi-square and reduced chi-square
(chisqr and redchi). The standard errors or  uncertainties are those that
increase chi-square by 1. Since a “good fit” should have redchi of around 1,
this requires that the data uncertainties (and to some extent the sampling
of the N data points) is correct. Unfortunately, it is often not the case
that one has high-quality estimates of the data uncertainties (getting the
data is hard enough!). Because of this common situation, the uncertainties
reported and held in stderr are not those that increase chi-square by 1, but
those that increase chi-square by reduced chi-square. This is equivalent to
rescaling the uncertainty in the data such that reduced chi-square would be
1. To be clear, this rescaling is done by default because if reduced 
chi-square is far from 1, this rescaling often makes the reported uncertainties 
sensible, and if reduced chi-square is near 1 it does little harm. If you 
have good scaling of the data uncertainty and believe the scale of the
residual array is correct, this automatic rescaling can be turned off using
scale_covar=False.
```

Comment: I am not very knowledgeable about statistics. As shown my printout of the fit statistics shows chi-square         = 5.6981e-29
reduced chi-square      = 1.0635e-32
I have read the cited text several times, but I do not understand what I should do. If you could indicate what I have to change or add in my code it would be most helpful

Comment: For a properly scaled chi-square, you need to scale the residual (data - model) to the uncertainty in the data.  If you have uncertainty value or array, use `model.fit(....,  weight=1.0/eps_data)`  where `eps_data` is the estimated uncertainty in the data.   You did not include enough of example to give a more specific answer.

Comment: @rbaer  Using `weight=1./0.05` is saying that the y-values have an absolute uncertainty of 0.05, not "5%". Like, what do you mean by 5%? Do you mean 5% of the point-by-point value of y?  If so, explicitly state that:  `weight=20./y`.  Might want to check for divide-by-zero there...

Comment: I tried 
'''
result = mod.fit(y,pars,x=x, scale_covar=False, weight=1.0/0.05) 
'''
as well as scale_covar= True 
assuming a 5% uncertainty; the  output did not change.
If you give your email address I could send you my complete code, which is not much longer than what I posted, and the data file.

Comment: I cannot guess why you think `scale_covar=True` would be associated with "5% uncertainty".  You need to include a minimal, complete example that shows the problem you are having.  If you do not want to use SO, then read the actual docs, including how to get help.  The answer won't be different than "for chi-square to have the correct scale you need to include the uncertainties in the data".  Not the percentage or fractional uncertainties - the actual uncertainties.